# How to record shell commands of all ssh sessions of all users accessing the same router/server to a log file in linux?

Tags: linux, sshd

without using any built-in commands like history because if history is cleared all commands will be gone,but in my log file it must be present every time.
As per my understanding,
1.A daemon should start running in background when user login through ssh, it redirects all commands to a log file.
2.Log file should have max of 500 commands(done through logrotate.conf)

Whether I have to to code change in sshd daemon? or how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "ssh sessions ... accessing the same router/server"? You want to log the history of users that connect to the server via SSH? And what for? Are you aware that there are many ways to issue commands that won't show in any history?

Comment: Forget SSH snooping and use true [system auditing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7)

Comment: Any user connected to a particular network login through ssh.The commands entered by the user should be directly recorded to the log file(not using history).

Comment: So, use system auditing. You can't tell what a script (or an `untar`...) does under the hood.

Comment: As audit tool will not work for my platform.I tried with script command but the output is not in readable form and it is not capturing the commands instantly.Can you please suggest me any other way to store commands of multiple sessions in log file.

Comment: Then change the platform. You are fooling yourself it you think you can record all malevolent (or even accidental) actions that way...

Comment: What Unix are you running that does not support proper auditing or process accounting?

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to start auditd sevice:Error - audit support not in kernel,Cannot open netlink audit socket, What is the kernel config file/module for auditd tool? I am not allowed to upgrade kernel. Please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "user command". There are lines of input, but you can't tell if they are commands (read by the top-level shell) or inputs to applications, and this latter case would include commands in a second-level shell. Then you don't know what happens in screen-based editors (`nano`, `vi`) and you don't know what scripts do.